# Changing horizontal line colour

Tags: color, tcolorbox

I'm using:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\definecolor{fucsia}{RGB}{196,0,98}


\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
\arrayrulecolor{fucsia}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{!{\color{fucsia}\vline} l !{\color{white}\vline}}{\cellcolor{fucsia}\color{white}\textbf{Suffix}} & \multicolumn{1}{l !{\color{white}\vline}}{\cellcolor{fucsia}\color{white}\textbf{Agregar a}} & \multicolumn{1}{l !{\color{white}\vline}}{\cellcolor{fucsia}\color{white}\textbf{Significado}} & \multicolumn{1}{l !{\color{fucsia}\vline}}{\cellcolor{fucsia}\color{white}\textbf{Ejemplo}}\\
\rowcolor{white}
-y & sustantivos &  & snowy \\
\rowcolor{white}
 &  &  & lucky \\
\hline
\rowcolor{white}
-ly & sustantivos &  & friendly \\
\rowcolor{white}
 &  & with the & weekly \\
\hline
\rowcolor{white}
-ous & sustantivos & quality of & dangerous \\
\rowcolor{white}
 &  &  & mysterious \\
\hline
\rowcolor{white}
-al & sustantivos &  & economical \\
\rowcolor{white}
 &  &  & national \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

What I want to do is to change to while colour the horizontal lines of the third column. Except the one at the end which completes the edge of the table.

Comment: Maybe have a look at the `multirow` package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `hhline` package as it doesn't conflict with row coloring.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{fucsia}{RGB}{196,0,98}
\usepackage{hhline}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
\arrayrulecolor{fucsia}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{!{\color{fucsia}\vline} l !{\color{white}\vline}}{\cellcolor{fucsia}\color{white}\textbf{Suffix}} & \multicolumn{1}{l !{\color{white}\vline}}{\cellcolor{fucsia}\color{white}\textbf{Agregar a}} & \multicolumn{1}{l !{\color{white}\vline}}{\cellcolor{fucsia}\color{white}\textbf{Significado}} & \multicolumn{1}{l !{\color{fucsia}\vline}}{\cellcolor{fucsia}\color{white}\textbf{Ejemplo}}\\
\rowcolor{white}
-y & sustantivos &  & snowy \\
\rowcolor{white}
 &  &  & lucky \\
\hhline{--~-}
\rowcolor{white}
-ly & sustantivos &  & friendly \\
\rowcolor{white}
 &  & with the & weekly \\
\hhline{--~-}
\rowcolor{white}
-ous & sustantivos & quality of & dangerous \\
\rowcolor{white}
 &  &  & mysterious \\
\hhline{--~-}
\rowcolor{white}
-al & sustantivos &  & economical \\
\rowcolor{white}
 &  &  & national \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with `hhline`. I took the opportunity to simplify your code: `\rowcolor{white}` isn't necessary.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{fucsia}{RGB}{196,0,98}
\usepackage{hhline}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
\arrayrulecolor{fucsia}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{!{\color{fucsia}\vline} l !{\color{white}\vline}}{\cellcolor{fucsia}\color{white}\textbf{Suffix}} & \multicolumn{1}{l !{\color{white}\vline}}{\cellcolor{fucsia}\color{white}\textbf{Agregar a}} & \multicolumn{1}{l !{\color{white}\vline}}{\cellcolor{fucsia}\color{white}\textbf{Significado}} & \multicolumn{1}{l !{\color{fucsia}\vline}}{\cellcolor{fucsia}\color{white}\textbf{Ejemplo}}\\
-y & sustantivos & & snowy \\
 & & & lucky \\
\hhline{---~}
-ly & sustantivos & & friendly \\
 & & with the & weekly \\
\hhline{---~}
-ous & sustantivos & quality of & dangerous \\
 & & & mysterious \\
\hhline{---~}
-al & sustantivos & & economical \\
 & & & national \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The reason why I added `\rowcolor{white}` is because I'll put this table in a chart, and the chart has a different colour. It's just style.

Comment: I see. Sorry for removing it. What I had not seen is AboAmmar had posted (almost) the same code. I'll remove my answer in a moment. Comment aside: in my opinion,  no white vertical rules in the first row would be nicer.